# How can I set timeOffset attribute from TimeLayout tag?

Tags: android, widget, sony-smartwatch

```
<com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.widget.TimeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@color/smart_watch_2_text_color_white"
    widgets:gravity="center"
    app:timeOffset="10800" >

    <!-- Defines the hour digits by using a TimeView the timeType to
    hours. -->
    <com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.widget.TimeView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        widgets:textSize="match_parent"
        widgets:timeType="hours" />
</com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.widget.TimeLayout>
```

On the ClockWidget example from Sony Add-on SDK version 3, when I try to set the timeOffset attribute above, the clock displays the hour properly, but when I change the timeOffset and runs the code again, the hour don't update, excepts when I uninstall the app on the phone and runs again.

So, how to change properly timeOffset attribute by xml and by code in a class which extends BaseWidget class?

I'm trying to develop for SmartWatch 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create as many xml layouts, as many time zones you need, e.g.:

```
<com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.widget.TimeLayout
    widgets:timeOffset="-3600"
```

for time zone -1 hour,

```
<com.sonyericsson.extras.liveware.aef.widget.TimeLayout
    widgets:timeOffset="3600"
```

for time zone +1 hour, etc. Then all you need to change time zones dynamically is to switch layouts in your java file.